# getLastLocation return null when connected to WiFi

Tags: android, location

ALL,

I have following issue. Here 's the code excerpt:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.main_radar );
    int res = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable( getApplicationContext() );
    if( res != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS )
    {
        if( BuildConfig.DEBUG )
            Log.i( "Radar", "Check failed!" );
        return;
    }
    if( servicesConnected() )
    {
        client = new LocationClient( this, this, this );
    }
    else
        return;
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    if( client != null )
        client.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0)
{
    currLocation = client.getLastLocation();
    device.setLatitude( currLocation.getLatitude() );
    device.setLongtitude( currLocation.getLongitude() );
}
```

Initially I tried to running this code when connecting to my 4G signal and I immediately received the location from getLastLocation() call. However, yesterday I tried to connect to my LAN WiFi. The program crashed.

Trying to investigate I found out that the call to getLastLocation() returns null. However the connection was successful.

Now, my question is: I understand that getLastLocation() returning location almost immediately might be a good luck and me testing on the WiFi connection reveals a bug in the code. But what is the best way to fix it?

It seems people suggests using location updates. I'm not developing some kind of map application. I just need this once on the start and thats it.

So, is getting location updates the best approach? Will it work with WiFi enabled? What is the usual time frame to get the location? If I set the time to wait for the updates as too small I might not receive any.

Or maybe it should not work by definition?

Could someone please sched some light here.

Thank you in advance for any hints/points.

Comment: GetLastLocation can return null if it hasn't found a location yet.  You have to account for that possibility.  If you don't want to run code until a location exists, ask for location updates instead.

Comment: @GabeSechan, its not that I don't want. I'm asking for the best approach here. Besides what if I select too small timeframe for location updates? Or maybe use an AsyncTask to check for the non-null value? This way I can show the progress dialog if there is no location yet....

Comment: @Igor you may subscribe LocationListener for location updates, then unsubscribe it when first location arrives. It will be accessible via Wifi if user enabled Google location services on his device.

Comment: @Igor and you don't need any kinds of async task for that. Launch app -> Show waiting dialog -> Subscribe for updates. First update arrives -> Hide the dialog -> Unsubscribe LocationListener.

Comment: @Salauyou, is there a recommended time to set to wait for it to come? I know it depends on many things, but....

Comment: @igor first network location update usually arrives after a few seconds. You can set a timer to 10 seconds, and if onLocatonChange callback wasn't invoked before timer finishes, try to get lastKnownLocation. If there is null, so network location cannot be obtained--show the dialog "please check internet connection and location preferences".

Comment: @Salauyou, thank you. That works. But I still puzzled: why there is a time difference like this? Is it because I have a lower speed on my LAN than 4G of the ATT service?

Comment: No, it's just because of asynchronous approach in location manager work